# Default values in custom annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

I'm new in JAVA. I created a new custom annotation for custom validation in SPRING, but when I run the app I see this error:

> ```
>   The annotation @CourseCode must define the attribute groups
>   The annotation @CourseCode must define the attribute message
>   The annotation @CourseCode must define the attribute payload
>   The annotation @CourseCode must define the attribute value
> ```

Here is my implementation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Constraint(validatedBy = CourseCodeConstraintValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CourseCode {
    public String value() default "course-";

    public String message() default "must start with course-";

    public Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

Here is my usage

```
    @CourseCode
    private String courseCode;
```

Here is my CourseCodeConstraintValidator.

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class CourseCodeConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CourseCode, String>{

    private String coursePrefix;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CourseCode courseCode) {
        coursePrefix = courseCode.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String code, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

        boolean result = code.startsWith(coursePrefix);

        return result;
    }
}
```

I expected the default values I defined in the class would be used.

Comment: can't say I can see a reason why they shouldn't be. Did you forget to recompile the code after altering it?

Comment: @Stultuske, Nope, I recompile, restart the server, and so on several times. I'm really confused :(

Comment: Please show CourseCodeConstraintValidator code, because you said "when I run the app"...

Comment: @p3consulting added to the post 

Comment: Can't reproduce here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of hours of research, I gave up for a couple of days. Now I came back to it and suddenly discovered that switching perspective in eclipse after restarting the PC has done the trick and now it works as I expected.
Thanks to everybody who tried to help.